# A composition series for the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}20)\oplus (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}27)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

> Find $l_{\mathbb{Z}}((\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}20)\oplus (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}27))$.
>
> Determine a composition series for the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}20)\oplus (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}27)$

It's easy to see that $(\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}20)$ has a composition series
$$0=(\mathbb{Z}20 / \mathbb{Z}20) \subset (\mathbb{Z}10 / \mathbb{Z}20) \subset (\mathbb{Z}5 / \mathbb{Z}20) \subset (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}20)$$
Similarly $(\mathbb{Z}27 / \mathbb{Z}27) \subset (\mathbb{Z}9 / \mathbb{Z}27) \subset (\mathbb{Z}3 / \mathbb{Z}27) \subset (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}27)$

But I don't know how to find a composition of $(\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}20)\oplus (\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z}27)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite length modules, that is, admitting composition series. If $0=A_0\subset A_1\subset\dots\subset A_m=A$ and $0=B_0\subset B_1\subset\dots\subset B_n=B$ are composition series, then
$$
0=A_0\oplus0\subset A_1\oplus0\subset\dots\subset A_n\oplus 0
\subset A\oplus B_1\subset\dots\subset A\oplus B_n
$$
is a composition series for $A\oplus B$.

Comment: Thank you @egreg